# Beach waves project - Fluid dissapears over time

Tags: fluid-simulation

I try to make my own beach waves simulation like the ones one can find over and over on YouTube.
In order to test the animation of the fluid waves, I prepared a small test project, in order to be able to bake the fluid fast for different settings.
I'm stuck at the problem that whatever I do, the fluid almost completely disappears after 500 frames.
Here are two images after baking at frame 1 and frame 500:

[image]
[image]

I tried many different things like adding surface thickness to the effector objects in my scene or using the "is planar" option (although I have to admit that I don't fully understand the usage of this option...).

This is the fifth incarnation of my beach simulator, in which I build the thickness into the effector objects themself, but it does not work either.
I normalized the scale to 1,1,1 like I read in another thread.
I totally run out of ideas what the reason for the fluid disappearing could be.

Here is my blend file: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I tried to add the inflow as Chris suggested. The inflow above the pusher will seriously affect the wave generation and generates chaos.

I understand that the only way to prevent the water from disappearing is to add an inflow.
I did it like this now: [image]

The chaos is compensated a little bit...

Still, I wonder how all the beautiful beach wave simulations on YouTube are made, where each wave is rolling really beautiful.
Or is it just clever editing in the end?!?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a common problem of FLIP:

https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/issues/326

A workaround might be to use an inflow to compensate it. I tried this with your simulation and it worked pretty well:

[image]

As you can see (the orange box is the inflow) there is still lots of water in your domain).

Comment: I also tried inflow for compensation in between sometime but I didn't get it right either because, as a beginner, I was not able to set the right amount. Can you share the blend file so that I can see, what you did? In any way, thank you for your answer as I was about to Go crazy. At least, I have an explanation...